# How to fix syntax error 'continue' not properly in a loop in python

Tags: python, database, loops, deadlock

> I want to create a simple database, which will store and return data.

The problem is that `continue` doesn't seem to work.
Once the `else statement` in `function checker` is executed it keeps printing *"try again"* and seems to be deadlocked.

```
def checker(): 
#Checks if the password is strong enough
while True:
   if (p[0].isupper() and not p.isalpha() and len(p) > 7):
   print('Password Created!')
   break
#If password is not strong enough try again
else:
    print('Try Again')
    continue


#Starts main program
while True:
  database = {'dom':'yeet'}
  welcome = input('Welcome! To login press L, if you are new press R: ')
  #Login will log basically check if your info is in dictionary
  if welcome == 'L':
    for user in database.keys():
      u = input('Username: ')
      if u in user:
          for passw in database.values():
            p = input('Password: ')
            if p in passw:
               print('Welcome ' + str(u))
               break
  #Will create new user in dictionary
  elif welcome == 'R':
    u = input('Choose your username: ')
    p = input('Choose your password: ')

  #Runs checker function
    checker()

    database[u] = p
    print('Welcome ' + str(u))
    break
 else:
    continue
```

Comment: you need to read up when you can use continue and what kind of loops accept it, this is something a beginner should look for in the docs

Comment: I fixed, it was bad intendendation from start of func, but now I have other bug, else spams try again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rewrite checker() like this:
You used incorrect indentation for the else block, and it was out of the loop.

```
def checker(): 
    #Checks if the password is strong enough
    while True:
        if (p[0].isupper() and not p.isalpha() and len(p) > 7):
            print('Password Created!')
            break

        else:
            print('Try Again')
            continue
```

Answer (score 1):

The beauty of Python coding is you must indent code properly, keeping that in mind ,  automatically everybody writes beautiful code, and you'll never see a Python code with bad formating. 
Indent your else part and you are good to go.